# Explicitly inject a bean marked @Component

Tags: java, spring

So for some reason half our project's beans are marked with @Component and injected into other objects marked @Component with the @Autowired annotation, while the other half is wired up explicitly with appliciationContext.xml bean declarations and properties with ref beans values.

Question is, in those xml bean declarations, can I inject one of the objects marked @Component? If so, what will its bean reference name be?

For example;

Some classes are annotated like so;

```
@Component
public class BeanAImpl{ ... }
```

Then in applicationContext.xml other classes are wired explicitly as they are not annotated;

```
<bean id="beanB" class="com.myapp.BeanBImpl"></bean>
```

Can I inject both 'kinds' of beans in applicationContext.xml?

```
<bean id="beanUser" class="com.myapp.BeanUserImpl">
    <property name="beanA">HOW_TO_GET_REF_TO_BEANA?</property>
    <property name="beanB"><ref bean="beanB"/></property>
</bean>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default name for `@Component` of type `BeanAImpl` is `beanAImpl`, you can use it in XML as you do with manually declared beans (also note that `<property>` allows shorter syntax):

```
<property name="beanA" ref = "beanAImpl" />
```

Alternatively, you can explicitly set a name as `@Component("beanA")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what Spring says:

When a component is autodetected as part of the scanning process, its bean name will be generated by the BeanNameGenerator strategy known to that scanner.
If you don't want to rely on the default bean-naming strategy, you may provide a custom bean-naming strategy. First, implement the BeanNameGenerator interface, and be sure to include a default no-arg constructor. Then, provide the fully-qualified class name when configuring the scanner:

```
 <context:component-scan base-package="org.example"
                         name-generator="org.example.MyNameGenerator" />
```

The deafault implementation is just the class name starting with loer case.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `@Component`, I think you want to use `@Resource(name="your_id_here")`, and then you can `<ref>` it like you're doing with beanB.  Give it a shot.

Source: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s11.html#beans-resource-annotation